# Keras produce different index per training step

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras, dropout

I want to implement "Controlled Dropout" similar to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.03109.pdf).

I have a list containing the dropout configurations as bernoulli vectors and I want all of them to be used during training.
To define a counter and circle through the list does not work, probably because of a lot optimization going on with fitting the network.
The current idea is to index from the list by using `keras.backend.random.randint(0, self.max_dropout_configs)`, however it is hard to verify if this solution works.
Do you know if `keras.backend.random.randint` returns a different int per training step, or just one in the beginning?

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

`keras.backend` is based on TensorFlow which have a random seed that you can set manually so that it generate the same integer at each training step.

```
np.random.seed(123)
tf.random.set_seed(123)
```

You can add these seeds in the beginning of your code and it must get solved.

Comment: Ok, but the seed only obtains that the random number is reproducible/deterministic.
Without seed, the number would still be the same at each training step?

Comment: without setting a random seed for tensorflow, the `keras.backend.random.randint` will return a different int each time it's called which means per training step